# StringToWordVector Weka Output

Tags: nlp, weka, text-mining

I have an arff file containing a set of textual sentences. I would like to 
obtain the absolute frequency of each word within each sentence. I used StringToWordVector.

This is the starting file

`@relation dataset 
 @attribute Text string 
 @date 
 'I'm a movie lover and this is one of the best museums in which ...`

After running StringToWordVector I get instances of this type:

`@relation dataset1
@attribute word numeric
...
{13 2, 19 2, 30 2, 33 1, 53 1, 55 4, 60 1, 61 2, 72 3, 78 1, 89 1, 90 1, 99 
1, 106 1,120 1,121 1,123 2,124 5,126 2,136 1,140 1,147 5,148 2,160 1,186 
1,198 1,202 1,248 9,253 1, ...}`

Since I would like to keep track of the word, instead of using a numeric id, how can I associate the textual word to the frequency obtained after the execution of the stringtowordvector command?

Answer (score 0):

This question was also asked on the Weka mailing list:

https://list.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2019-April/047670.html

The [StringToWordVector](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html) outputs data in *sparse format*, where the first value is the 0-based index of the attribute and the second the actual value:

https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/arff_stable/#sparse-arff-files

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to manipulate this sparse matrix? for example making aggregations on all the instances for each index so as to obtain the total frequency of each attribute on all documents.

Comment: You can access the data in sparse format just like any other Weka dataset. Both, `weka.core.SparseInstance` and `weka.core.DenseInstance` both implement `weka.core.Instance`, which make up the rows in a `weka.core.Instances` dataset structure.